# Dynamic set image path

Tags: android

In my project, there are a number of images having back and forward images and all images having a common layout. On clicking back and next buttons new images should be displayed.

```
private int imageCounter = 0;
private ImageView imageView;
private int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.image_w_lbl_0, R.drawable.image_w_lbl_1,};
private int index_count = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    setContentView(R.layout.frame0);//this one is the common parent layout for all imageviews
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imageView = new ImageView(this);

    ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    ImageButton back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);

    //show the default image
    this.loadImage(imageArray[0]);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    int imagePath = 0;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.next:
        if(imageCounter < 25)
        {   
            imagePath = imageArray[index_count];
        }
        imageCounter++;
        break;
    case R.id.back:
        if(imageCounter > 0)
        {
            //imagePath =
        }
        imageCounter--;

        break;      
    }
    this.loadImage(imagePath);
}

private void loadImage(int imagePath)
{
    imageView.setImageResource(imagePath);
}
```

I am able to see my layout only in the output having back and forward buttons with the black background not an image from my drawable folder.

XML Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/back" android:src="@drawable/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to get this info in your Android app or in your build environment. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int array of images from resources (i.e. res/drawable-mdpi):

`Integer[] imageArray = { "R.drawable.img1", "R.drawable.img2" }`

`...`

`imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[0]); // displays img1`

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear what you are asking, but do you want to do something like this:

imagePath=R.drawable.image_wo_lbl_0;
You can store image path in this way, if you actually want to do this.

Comment: how to make this dynamin depending upon count value means for count=0 get the path of particular image;for count =1 get the path of another image...and so on.just pass imagePath as arguemnt in the method loadimage and show that image in imageview.that's it!!!

Comment: hi viv!thanks i have done something as above edited code running fine but not able to load image from my drawable folder is there something wrong with imageView.setImageResource(imagePath);.one thing also i am confuse is that, will my image view overlap to my next and back buttons? see my xml please having to image buttons!!i have taken the above layout as parent container for all images to be loaded

Comment: "will my image view overlap to my next and back buttons", well i am not able to judge it, sorry for it,  for imageview try using imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[0])........ hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way - Can be consider the below code

We can take advantage of Imageview setImageResource , refer below code for the same.
 put image in the drawable like the below order

image_1.png, image_2.png, etc.

```
int imagePosition = 1;                    

int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("image_" + imagePosition, "drawable", getPackageName());
             imageview.setImageResource(resId);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `ContextCompat` to get drawable(Image in your case). This is one of the new ways to set image to your image view.

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
                                                     R.drawable.your_image));
```

You can use `ContextCompat` to get colors as well.
I use it in my apps and it works properly.